# Setup a Kibana dashboard for data about last Jenkins build

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins, automation, kibana

I use Kibana to show data about automated test cases stored in a single elastic search index.

These tests can be repeated multiple times during the day and right now are identified by a build number that comes from Jenkins. So, if I want to see the latest results, I need to add a filter in my dashboards where I set the last known value of the build number.

Is there a way to automatically show in a dashboard the values about the last build?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here's a data sample:

```
{
  "_index": "data",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "33rugH0B0CwJH7IcV11v",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "market": "FRA",
    "price_code": "DIS22FREH1003",
    "test_case_id": "NPM_14",
    "environment": "PROD",
    "cruise_id": "DI20220707CPVCP1",
    "jenkins_job_name": "MonitoringNPM_14",
    "@timestamp": "2021-12-03T16:34:03.360+0100",
    "jenkins_job_number": 8,
    "agency": "FR900000",
    "fail_code": "IncorrectGuarantee",
    "build_number": 8,
    "category": "IR2"
  },
  "fields": {
    "environment.keyword": [
      "PROD"
    ],
    "test_case_id": [
      "NPM_14"
    ],
    "category.keyword": [
      "IR2"
    ],
    "price_code": [
      "DIS22FREH1003"
    ],
    "cruise_id": [
      "DI20220707CPVCP1"
    ],
    "price_code.keyword": [
      "DIS22FREH1003"
    ],
    "agency": [
      "FR900000"
    ],
    "jenkins_job_number": [
      "8"
    ],
    "agency.keyword": [
      "FR900000"
    ],
    "jenkins_job_number.keyword": [
      "8"
    ],
    "market": [
      "FRA"
    ],
    "jenkins_job_name.keyword": [
      "MonitoringNPM_14"
    ],
    "test_case_id.keyword": [
      "NPM_14"
    ],
    "environment": [
      "PROD"
    ],
    "@timestamp": [
      "2021-12-03T15:34:03.360Z"
    ],
    "jenkins_job_name": [
      "MonitoringNPM_14"
    ],
    "fail_code.keyword": [
      "IncorrectGuarantee"
    ],
    "fail_code": [
      "IncorrectGuarantee"
    ],
    "build_number": [
      8
    ],
    "market.keyword": [
      "FRA"
    ],
    "cruise_id.keyword": [
      "DI20220707CPVCP1"
    ],
    "category": [
      "IR2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a data sample from your elasticsearch cluster (in json) to check whic data are stored in elk?

Comment: Thank you, I've just added a sample.